# how to receive EJS render data send from node ,in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, render, ejs

I am sending some data from node server file and trying to get that value in jquery and display it. I know how to display data in HTML using <%= variable_name %>. But I want to handle that data from my jquery. How can I do that?

node file

```
app.get("/", function (request, response){
    response.render('index.ejs',{data:"hello"}); 
});
```

index.ejs

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //var data = <%= data %>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is a string you should be able to do like that:

```
var data = "<%= data %>";
```

If it's a diferent type, like an array or object, you could do:

```
var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
```